# Posing a character with the help of motion tracking

Tags: animation, pose-mode, motion-capture

I'm new to blender and motion tracking, and I need some help.
I'm wanna know that Can I pose a character with the help of motion tracking from video footage in blender?How?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: track elements that would correspond with the controls on the rig. Use the trackers as empties using "link empty to track", then use those empties to control the bones in your rig.

Comment: Can I do this without having hardware such as kinect? and just with the recorded video?